# What makes this equation "exponential of quadratic", and how is this distribution derived from it?

Tags: bayesian, likelihood, quadratic-form

I am studying machine learning and I am confused by one of the derivations in our textbook. I have two questions:

1. what makes equation 3.10 a "exponential of a quadratic function of w"?
2. How is the distribution of p(w) derived here?

Here is the relevant excerpt from my textbook:

> We begin our discussion of the Bayesian treatment of linear regression
>   by introducing a prior probability distribution over the model
>   parameters w. [...] First note that the likelihood
>   function p(t|w) defined by (3.10) **is the exponential of a quadratic
>   function of w**. The corresponding conjugate prior **is therefore given by**
>   a Gaussian distribution of the form
>
> > [image]
> >
> > (equation 3.10):
> >
> > [image]

Comment: What does the notation "$\mathcal{N}$" mean to you?  Do you have a mathematical definition?

Comment: Sorry, it is the normal distribution:
(1/sqrt(2pi * sigma^2))*e^-(x-mu)^2/(2sigma^2)). Or at least, the multivariate version of that.

Comment: Exactly: doesn't that look like an exponential of a quadratic function of $\mu$?

Answer (score 1):

So look at that normal density you mention in comments, for an univariate $w$:

$p(w) =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} s_0}\cdot e^{-\frac{1}{2s_0^2}(w-m_0)^2}$

Pulling the constant into the exponent:

$p(w) =e^{c_0-(w-m_0)^2/(2s_0^2)}=e^{q_0(w)}$

where $c_0 = \frac12 \log(2\pi s_0^2)$

so now it's an exponentiation of some function $q_0$

But what's $q_0$? It's a quadratic in $w$:

$q_0(w) = c_0-(w-m_0)^2/(2s_0^2) = a w^2 + bw + c$

(I'll leave you to expand it out and see what $a,b,$ and $c$ are).

The multivariate version follows the same kind of reasoning - if you write it out, in the exponent you have a quadratic form in $\mathbf{w}$.